# Ansible: Configure global variable which "environments" to set up

Tags: ansible

I want to be able to setup via ansible different "environments" (sets of same variables), e.g. production, testing, staging, etc.

I would like to:

1. define which environments to set up (`setup_environments`) at some global place
2. run a role r1 once for each environment in `setup_environments`
3. run a role r2 without setting its environment, but r2 should have access both to the variable `setup_environments` AND be able to load the defined environments for certain tasks.

Is this possible? 3. should be possible with `include_vars`, but I mention it to show that I really need the "setup_environments" variable and can't simply run ansible multiple times including each environment separately with `-i`.

Comment: Put each environment in its own inventory.

Answer (score 1):

Reading your requirement it seems that you need to [structure your inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html) only. Let's assume your inventory looks like

**inventory.ini**

```
[environment:children]
prod
qa
dev

webserver
database

[environment:vars]
# No global variables here / yet

[prod:children]
webserver_prod
database_prod

[qa:children]
webserver_qa
database_qa

[dev:children]
webserver_dev
database_dev

# Logical services nodes

[webserver:children]
webserver_prod
webserver_qa
webserver_dev

[database:children]
database_prod
database_qa
database_dev

# List of all hosts

# [prod:children]

[webserver_prod]
web.prod.example.com

[database_prod]
primary.prod.example.com
secondary.prod.example.com

# [qa:children]

[webserver_qa]
web.qa.example.com

[database_qa]
primary.qa.example.com
secondary.qa.example.com

# [dev:children]

[webserver_dev]
web.dev.example.com

[database_dev]
primary.dev.example.com
secondary.dev.example.com
```

you may get familar with the structure than by

```
ansible-inventory dev --graph
ansible-inventory database_dev --graph
...
```

It will be possible to apply playbooks, tasks, etc. just [to certain nodes](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_patterns.html) via

```
ansible-playbook database_dev ...
```

Furthermore you should [introduce `group_vars`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#organizing-host-and-group-variables) like

```
all
prod
qa
dev
webserver_prod
database_prod
...
```

All depdends on the structure of the inventory but makes it easier afterwards.

Comment: Actually all my services run on the same host, does this make sense anyways? How do I solve my step 2? I want to define a variable (e.g. "setup_environments") somewhere and then run a task for some host/service once for each defined variable group. So for example, a task for a group "server_setup" should run once with the defined variables in "prod" and once for the variables in "dev" - because the server setup needs access to both environments to set them up on one server. Could you maybe concretize your answer referring to the points in my question?